# Incorrect integral in textbook?

Tags: calculus

I saw this integral in my textbook. Is this incorrect? Shouldn't it be $-\lambda e^{-\lambda s}$ since the integral of $e^{-\lambda s}$ is $-\frac{1}{\lambda}e^{-\lambda s}$

> \begin{align*}
> f_S(s) &=\lambda^2\int_0^se^{-\lambda s}\,dt\\
> &=\lambda^2se^{-\lambda s}
> \end{align*}

[Image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jMtAQ.png)

Comment: You are integrating with respect to t, not s. Where's the t in the integral?

Comment: @GrahamKemp yeah as I stated in my comment below, I was thrown off by the fact that they moved $\lambda^{2}$ outside of the integral but left the rest inside. Thought maybe the dt was a typo and was supposed to read ds. In any case, thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The integral is with respect to $t$, not $s$.   So $\mathsf e^{-\lambda s}$ is relatively constant to $t$.

$$\begin{align}
f(s) & = \lambda^2\int_0^s \mathsf e^{-\lambda s}\operatorname d t \\[1ex]
& = \lambda^2 ~\mathsf e^{-\lambda s}\int_0^s \operatorname d t \\[1ex]
& = \lambda^2 ~\mathsf e^{-\lambda s}~(s-0)\\[1ex]
& = \lambda^2 ~s ~\mathsf e^{-\lambda s}
\end{align}$$

Comment: Small typo: You mean $s$ as the upper limit.

Comment: @GrahamKemp ah, gotcha. That's what I thought, but it seemed weird that the book moved $\lambda^{2}$ outside of the integral while it kept $e^{-\lambda s}$ inside, don't you think?

Comment: ?doh!  @HowDoIMath Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

$$\lambda^2\int_0^s e^{-\lambda s}\,dt = \lambda^2e^{-\lambda s}\int_0^s\,dt = \lambda^2e^{-\lambda s}\big[t\big]
\bigg|_0^s = \lambda^2e^{-\lambda s}s = \lambda^2 se^{-\lambda s}.$$

Comment: Are math-only answers encouraged here, unlike code only answers on SO?

Comment: @tac  I wouldn't say they are encouraged. Long story short, they are acceptable.